# Check if value is present in an object or array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find, lodash

I have some data in the following format

```
var list2 = [
  {
    items:{ 
      val: 'a'
    }
  },
  {
    items:[
      {
        val: 'b'
      },
      {
        val: 'c'
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

I need to check if, for example, the list contains an item with `val = 'b'`.

As you can see, this is an array of objects with each an `items` property which could be a single object, or an array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Lodash

For a simple test which returns `true` if at least one item matches our searched property, [`_.some`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) would work.

```
function test(arr, matches) {
  return _.some(arr, obj => {
    var items = obj.items;
    // make non-array items an array.
    return _.some(!_.isArray(items) ? [items]: items, matches);
  });
}

var hasValA = test(list2, { val: 'a' });
```

```js
function test(arr, matches) {
  return _.some(arr, obj => {
    var items = obj.items;
    return _.some(!_.isArray(items) ? [items]: items, matches);
  });
}

var list1 = [{
    items: [{
      val: 'a'
    }]
  }],
  list2 = [{
    items: {
      val: 'a'
    }
  }, {
    items: [{
      val: 'b'
    }, {
      val: 'c'
    }, ]
  }],
  list3 = [{
    items: [{
      val: 'b'
    }]
  }];

var matches = {
  val: 'a'
};

console.log("list1:", test(list1, matches));
console.log("list2:", test(list2, matches));
console.log("list3:", test(list3, matches));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

## ES6

This would also be possible in plain ES6 with the help of

- [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```javascript
function test(arr, matches) {
  return arr.some(obj => {
    var items = obj.items;
    if (!Array.isArray(items)) items = [items];
    return items.some(obj => {
      return Object.keys(matches).every(key => matches[key] === obj[key]);
    });
  });
}

var hasValA = test(list2, { val: 'a' });
```

```js
function test(arr, matches) {
  return arr.some(obj => {
    var items = obj.items;
    if (!Array.isArray(items)) items = [items];
    return items.some(obj => {
      return Object.keys(matches).every(key => matches[key] === obj[key]);
    });
  });
}

var list1 = [{
    items: [{
      val: 'a'
    }]
  }],
  list2 = [{
    items: {
      val: 'a'
    }
  }, {
    items: [{
      val: 'b'
    }, {
      val: 'c'
    }, ]
  }],
  list3 = [{
    items: [{
      val: 'b'
    }]
  }];

var matches = {
  val: 'a'
};

console.log("list1:", test(list1, matches));
console.log("list2:", test(list2, matches));
console.log("list3:", test(list3, matches));
```

---

Both solutions would work with more a complex object to match against.

```
test(list2, { val: 'a', other: 2, /* ... */ });
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used the 'some' function, and also your method of checking and converting the single item to an array, and I now have this working in my project.

Comment: @JonathanShutt you should accept an answer, or if either have helped you enough, you could provide your own answer and accept it. If it's still unresolved, I encourage you to ask additional details in the comment sections of answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could pluck and flatten the items from the array using [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatmap) and then use [**some**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some):

```
var result = _(list2)
    .flatMap('items')
    .some({val: 'a'})
```